# React Native Expo QRcode generate each rectangle with BorderRadius

Tags: react-native, svg, qr-code

I'm using the react-native-qrcode-svg package, but when I try to implement a simple QR code, this image returns.

[image]

I already tried removing all the styles, but keep returning the same image,

this is the code that i am using

```
<QRCode value="http://awesome.link.qr"/>
```

**UPDATE**

I was reviewing the code of the package and I noticed that it uses the Path to draw each box, check in the documentation and for some reason it has the property by default

```
strokeLinecap={'square'}
```

I had to specify that it was square, I also had to modify the width and height of each square, because they are poorly positioned.
 I did that in the file

```
./node_modules/react-native-qrcode-svg/src/transformMAtrixIntoPath.js
```

I really don't know if I did it right, or there is another way much easier to solve, but for the moment that solved it

Answer (score 1):

For someone who has the same problem, I fixed it like this:

ADD `strokeLinecap={'square'}` on Line 141, as property of  at index.js file

Head to tranformMatrixIntoPath.js file and modify the algorithm

UPDATE Line 2 `add const cellSize = size / matrix.length - 0.1`
UPDATE Line 9 `add path += 'M${cellSize * j + 9} ${cellSize / 2 + cellSize * i}'`

Comment: yes, after several hours reviewing the react-svg documentation and the qr code library, i did exactly the same

Comment: Thanks this worked for me but had to change line to backticks not apostrophe:

path += `M${cellSize * j + 9} ${cellSize / 2 + cellSize * i}`